# I want to create a spiral motion of an object in C# for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I have created a C# script to define [spiral motion](https://qphs.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-e79cbabaac99270fbefb2efa35cac182.webp) of an object in a plane in 3D.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spiralanti : MonoBehaviour
{
    float angles;
    float radiuss;
    float angleSpeed;
    float rSpeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        angles = 0;
        radiuss = 10;
        angleSpeed = 150;
        rSpeed = 0.7f;
        angles = Mathf.Max(0, Mathf.PI);
        radiuss = Mathf.Max(0, radiuss);

        //float x = 0;
        // float y = 0;
        // float z = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        angles += Time.deltaTime * angleSpeed;
        radiuss -= Time.deltaTime * rSpeed;
        if (radiuss == 0)
        {
            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;
            float z = 0;

            transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        else
        {
            float x = radiuss * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angles);
            float z = radiuss * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angles);
            float y = 0;

            transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }


        }

 }
```

The object spirals very well, but I want to make it stop when it reaches origin and stay there. I have tried the if-else statement as given in the code, but it does not stop. Instead it becomes an outward spiral from an inward spiral.

Please help me with the code.

Comment: you mean change `if (radiuss == 0)` to this `if (radiuss <= 0)`

Comment: Because of rounding errors, the radius is probably never hitting exactly zero. Try changing your check to `if (radiuss <= 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Never use `==` for comparing two `float` values.

Due to [floating point imprecision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) the value might not exactly match the other one even if logically you would think so.

Example Unity uses if

```
10f / 10f != 1f
```

since sometimes this could be something like `1.00000001` or `0.999999999`.

**IF** you want to check exact values rather use [Mathf.Approximately](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(a,b))
```

which basically equals

```
if(Mathf.Abs(a-b) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
```

---

and then secondly your

```
radiuss -= Time.deltaTime * rSpeed;
```

allows overshooting so if before running this the `radiuss` is already `< Time.deltaTime * rSpeed` you end up with a negative value which is not exactly `== 0` but maybe `-0.00000001` or less so you never get into the `if` block.

---

So you could either simply use

```
if(radius <= 0)
{
   transform.position = Vector3.zero;
}
...
```

or you could definitely make sure it is not below `0` and do

```
radius = Mathf.Max(0, radius);
if(Mathf.Approximately(radius, 0))
{
    transform.position = Vector3.zero;
}
...
```